# API for search products from zuora

Tags: node.js, zuora, zuora-soap

There is an API(v1/catalog/products) for get all the products from zuora. Likewise is there any API available for search product by product-name from zuora?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is not.
I use [Zoql](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/Central_Platform/Query/ZOQL) for that (I search by SKU, but it's the same):

```
select Id from Product where Sku = '%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/v1/action/query` API call which lets you write the query string in the body of the request. This query string can also have filters.